# How I can start my Android SQLite Application without a Error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, arraylist

I want built a Android Application with a SQLite Database. I have two Java Classes. The First is the Contact Class ans the second the DatabaseHandle class for the operations how add, update etc...

I don't get a error but if I start my Application I become this message ...

[image]

Here is my **Contact** Class

```
package de.linde.sqlite;

public class Contact {

    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;

    public Contact(){}

    public Contact(int id,String name,String _phone_number){

        this._id = id; 
        this._name = name; 
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }

    public Contact(String name,String _phone_number){

        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number; 
    }

    public int getID(){

        return this._id; 
    }

    public void setID(int id){

        this._id = id; 
    }

    public String getName(){

        return this._name; 
    }

    public void setName(String name){

        this._name = name; 
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){

        return this._phone_number;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){

        this._phone_number = phone_number; 
    }
}
```

Here is my **DatabaseHandler** Class

```
package de.linde.sqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Datenbank version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    //Datenbankname
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    //Tabellenname
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    //Tabellenspalten
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                                        + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT," 
                                        + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); 
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CONTACTS); 

        onCreate(db); 
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
package de.linde.sqlite;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 
        db.addContact(new Contact("Wladimir","024324324"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Max","0324324324"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Benny","0324324"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("derSchwarze","051324324"));

        Log.d("Reading: ","Reading all Contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {

            String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            Log.d("Name: ", log); 
        }
    }

}
```

My **activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

What I make wrong :(

Comment: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error: CREATE TABLEcontacts(idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nameTEXT,phone_number TEXT) this is the Error that I get in the catch errormessage

Comment: we try like this it is very use full http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add spaces between the values that you add to `CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE` and the concatenated string, so you build a valid table creation string:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT)";
```

You'll need to uninstall the app from the phone/emulator and then run it again to make the database to be recreated again.

The same thing is valid for the String in the onUpgrade method:

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS
```

Comment: ok the i add spaces and now it create the database but the inserting don't work :/

Comment: @Tarasov If you have problems then post the exception you get from the logcat and point the line where it happens.

Comment: Error inserting phone_number= 024324324  name= Wladimir and android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named name: , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(phone_number, name) VALUES(?, ?);

Comment: @Tarasov There was a typo in my answer, I also forgot to add a space between `KEY_NAME` and `"TEXT,"`. Look at my string from my answer and update it in your app. And then reinstall the app again.

Comment: @Tarasov Indeed I just saw it. But where do you want to insert those contacts items? Right now you have a table named contacts (which isn't backed by the database in any way) and you try to insert something into that non existent table. So what are you trying to do? If you are trying to insert contacts in the phone's contacts then you can't do it like that, instead you need to use the `ContactsContract` provider.